# Printing php code with highlight_string

Tags: php

I am trying to show my code with highlight_string.  All of my variables are being stripped out of the printed code.  What am I doing wrong?  An example of what is happening ...

```
<?php highlight_string("
    <?
        $a=3;
        $b=4;
        if ($a < $b){
        echo 'a is less than b';
        }
    ?>"); 
?>
```

The output looks like this

```
    <?
        =3;
        =4;
        if ( < ){
        echo 'a is less than b';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the double quotes (") with single quotes (')
PHP tries to fill up variables printed within double quotes.

```
<?php highlight_string('
    <?
        $a=3;
        $b=4;
        if ($a < $b){
        echo \'a is less than b\';
        }
    ?>'); 
?>
```

Comment: And better use `NOWDOC` for this, so you don't need to escape so much.

Answer (score 1):

Tried using single quotes?

Using double quotes prints the values of variable rather than their defined names.

Answer (score 1):

When you use double quotes `"`, you allow PHP to replace all instances of a variable with its value.  For example, if I do this:

```
$a=5;
echo "$a";
```

My output will be:

```
5
```

If instead I did...

```
$a=5
echo '$a';
```

My output will be

```
$a
```

Answer (score 1):

In a php double-quoted string the dollar sign indicates that the variable after the dollar sign should be placed into the string, ie

```
 $a = 1;
 echo("A is $a");
 #prints A is 1
```

Even if $a is not defined, php will assume that you mean to create $a here:

```
 echo("A is $a");
 #prints A is
```

To get around this, use single quoted strings which take the string literally:

```
 echo('A is $a');
 #prints A is $a
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes not double

```
<?php highlight_string('
    <?
        $a=3;
        $b=4;
        if ($a < $b){
        echo \'a is less than b\';
        }
    ?>'); 
?>
```